# GAE taskqueue access application storage

Tags: google-app-engine

My GAE application is written in Python with webapp2. My application targets at analyzing user's online social network. Users could login and authorize my application, hence the access token will be stored for further crawling the data. Then i use the taskqueue to launch a backend task, as the crawling process is time consuming. However, when i access the datastore to fetch the access token, i can get it. I wonders whether there is a way to access the data of the frontend, rather than the temporary storage for the taskqueue.

## the handler to the process http request from the user

```
class Callback(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
       global client  
       global r 
       code = self.request.get('code')
       try:
           client = APIClient(app_key=APP_KEY, app_secret=APP_SECRET,redirect_uri=CALLBACK_URL)
           r = client.request_access_token(code)
           access_token = r.access_token  
           record = model.getAccessTokenByUid(r.uid)
           if record is None or r.access_token != record.accessToken:
               # logging.debug("access token stored")
               **model.insertAccessToken(long(r.uid), access_token, r.expires_in, "uncrawled", datetime.datetime.now())**  #data stored here  
    
           session = self.request.environ['beaker.session']
           session['uid'] = long(r.uid) 
           self.redirect(CLUSTER_PAGE % ("true"))
       except Exception, e:
           logging.error("callback:%s" % (str(e)));
           self.redirect(CLUSTER_PAGE % ("false"))
```

## the handle to process task submitted to taskqueue

```
   class CrawlWorker(webapp2.RequestHandler):
       def post(self):  # should run at most 1/s
           uid = self.request.get('uid')
           logging.debug("start crawling uid:%s in the backend" % (str(uid)))
           global client  
           global client1
           global r
    
           tokenTuple = model.getAccessTokenByUid(uid)
           if tokenTuple is None:    **#here i always get a None**
               logging.error("CounterWorker:oops, authorization token is missed.")
               return
```

Comment: Should this be "can't"? "when i access the datastore to fetch the access token, i can get it."

Comment: Where are you creating the task? Are you sure that it has the `uid` parameter? What is the output of that `debug` call in `CrawlWorker`?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear (is it can or cant?) But if you want to access frontend data from the taskqueue, pass it as parameters to the task queue.

Comment: It answers exactly what it was asked. Sustain your comments.